# Add a param in a collection in php

Tags: php, object, collections

Hy guys,
i have this problem, return this collection in php

```
[{name: "DayOffice", pax: 3, id: 2, location: "Eur", type: "DAYOFFICE"},
{name: "HotDesking", pax: 3, id: 3, location: "Eur", type: "HOTDESKING"}]
```

I would like something like that:

```
[{name: "DayOffice", pax: 3, id: 2, location: "Eur", type: "DAYOFFICE","price":xxxx},
{name: "HotDesking", pax: 3, id: 3, location: "Eur", type: "HOTDESKING","price":xxxx}]
```

please.

Thanks all

Comment: show us the function code through which you `return this collection in php`. Add that function code in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your collection/string is not valid/bad. To get what you want you've to make valid it by wrapping the keys with quotes `""` and then decode it as array and push your expected key to it e.g `price` with value `xxxx`.

```
$obj = '[{"name":"DayOffice","pax":3,"id":2,"location":"Eur","type":"DAYOFFICE"},{"name":"HotDesking","pax":3,"id":3,"location":"Eur","type":"HOTDESKING"}]';

$array = json_decode($obj,1);
foreach($array as $key=> $row){
    $array[$key]['price'] = 'xxxx';
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/XaNMf